# OpsHub fails at User Mapping @ getUserList

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am trying to migrate from an on premises TFS to online using OpsHub VSO Migration Tool, but it fails when it gets to the user mapping screen with the below error.  I have tried clearing the TFS cache and restarting the migration tool, but it still fails.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
10/14/2015 11:43:43,132 ERROR [http-8989-1] (com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl) - OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed getUserList. Server Error : Server was unable to process request. ---> There was an error generating the XML document. ---> TF20507: The string argument contains a character that is not valid:'u0153'. Correct the argument, and then try the operation again.
Parameter name: value
com.opshub.eai.tfs.exception.OIMTFSApiExcpetion: OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed getUserList. Server Error : Server was unable to process request. ---> There was an error generating the XML document. ---> TF20507: The string argument contains a character that is not valid:'u0153'. Correct the argument, and then try the operation again.
Parameter name: value
    at com.opshub.eai.tfs.adapter.TFSClient.getUserList(TFSClient.java:502)
    at com.opshub.eai.tfs.adapter.TFSAdapter.getUserList(TFSAdapter.java:550)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.business.ConfigServiceBusiness.getUserList(ConfigServiceBusiness.java:975)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl.getUserList(ConfigServiceImpl.java:408)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a8e82089.CGLIB$getUserList$6(<generated>)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a8e82089$$FastClassByCGLIB$$17643662.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:167)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ServiceInterception.intercept(ServiceInterception.java:48)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a8e82089.getUserList(<generated>)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigService.getUserList(ConfigService.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:453)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: HI, Can you share the trace as of the OpsHubTFSService.log file, that should point to the actual error. On a side note, a quick question, is your machine behind a proxy?

Comment: From the error that you sent us through email, it seems that there is a unicode character œ ('u0153\') present in either a user or a group of your TFS End Point. When the utility is trying to get the list of users, the api is unable to parse it. You will have to look into your user list and remove an occurrence of such character in order to continue. You can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912396/tf20507-the-string-argument-contains-a-character-that-is-not-validu0009-cor thread for more information.